# How to pass MongoClient object to Celery task

Tags: celery, pymongo, celery-task

I have a class `C` that contains a `MongoClient` object. It calls a celery task that expects an instance of `C` as an argument.

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mongoClient = MongoClient()

    def call_task(self):
        task.delay(self)

@app.task
def task(this):
    ...
```

This results in

> EncodeError(TypeError(u"'Database' object is not callable. If you meant to call the '**getnewargs**' method on a 'MongoClient' object it is failing because no such method exists.",),)

Any way I can pass an object containing a `MongoClient` to a celery task, or a pattern that allows me to hide the `MongoClient` from the task?

Comment: Have you tried a) `task(self)` to ensure it's a celery problem, and b) passing an instance of a MongoClient directly, rather than as an attribute of an object?

Comment: please paste in the full stack trace and the relevant code